# NoSuchMethodError with spring-webmvc upgrade

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

We upgraded to `spring-webmvc 5.2.3.RELEASE`.
This is causing a JUnit to fail.
I think the issue is with the `.build()` method - it can't be found.

The code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CommunicationDeliveryControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    CommunicationDeliveryController controller = new CommunicationDeliveryController();

    @Mock
    private RequestHandler requestHandler;

    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private CommunicationDeliveryController spiedController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        spiedController = spy(controller);
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(spiedController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void initiateBatchRunTest() throws Exception{
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/BatchRun").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).content(gson.toJson(BulkCommunicationRequestData.getBulkEmailRequestForPositive()))).andReturn();
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    public void deliverCommunicationTest() throws Exception{
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/deliverCommunication").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).content(gson.toJson(BulkCommunicationRequestData.populateAllEmailDetail()))).andReturn();
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }
}
```

The error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StandaloneConfiguration.getInterceptors()[Ljava/lang/Object;
        at company.custcomm.service.communicationdelivery.controllers.CommunicationDeliveryControllerTest.setup(CommunicationDeliveryControllerTest.java:45)
```

Are there compatibility issues between our versions of spring-webmvc, mockito, and JUnit?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You cannot just upgrade `spring-webmvc` you need to upgrade ALL spring dependencies to the same version. Errors/exceptions like this come from mixing jars from different versions of Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I upgrade all spring dependencies to 4.3.18-RELEASE, then there is no error any more.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific version of spring-test in your dependencies?

I ran into a similar problem a while ago - turned out that there was a strict version limit for spring-test, and upgrading it to 5.2.3-RELEASE resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the version of your Junit and spring-webmvc then you can specify spring-test version explicitly in your pom.xml. This works for me.

```xml
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
           <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```